# PHP won't recognize my RVM Ruby installation

Tags: php, ruby, rvm, centos5

**Background:** I'm building a website with PHP, and I need to have the website call a script that's written in Ruby 1.9. I'm using a CentOS 5.10 server that already had Ruby 1.8 installed on it, and I used RVM to upgrade to Ruby 1.9. When I type `ruby --version` from the command-line, it says I have Ruby 1.9 installed (as expected). However, when I use PHP to call `exec('ruby --version');`, it says I have Ruby 1.8 installed. In addition, when I use PHP to call `exec('which rvm');`, it does not return anything, even though I know RVM is installed.

**Question:** How can I allow PHP to use an RVM installation of Ruby 1.9 instead of the system installation of Ruby 1.8?

Comment: you must have installed `php` as a different user from the user used in installing `rvm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to keep in mind that the user that runs the web server process which executes your PHP script is *different* from you, the user, when using the command line.  To verify this, you can create a php script like the following:

```
<?php

print exec('whoami');
```

Run that script as yourself from the command line, and you'll see your username.  Put that script in a web accessible folder, and run it through your web browser (for example: `http://localhost/whoami.php`), and you'll probably see a username like `apache` or `www-data`.

You can also compare which ruby is running between you at the command line and your web browser.  Use the following php script:

```
<?php

print exec('which ruby');
```

Run that from the command line and then also run that in your web browser.  Those should be two different locations - and, of course, that's your core problem.

When you installed rvm, it's likely that a line of code was appended to your `.bash_profile` or `.profile` file in your home folder.  Look near the end of either of those files to see if there is a line that looks similar to this:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

This line initializes your shell environment every time you login or open a terminal so that rvm is accessible.  To verify this, you can create a php file with the following:

```
<?php

print exec('env | grep rvm');
```

Running this as yourself, from the command line, you should see lines related to `rvm_bin_path` and `rvm_path` and others.  But, put this script in a web accessible folder and run it from your browser - you'll notice that none of those lines are outputted to your browser.  That's because the *shell* that the PHP process spawns, when running as `www-data` user (or whatever user your web server runs as) doesn't have the same rvm initialization lines that your `` `.bash_profile `` script has.

One possible way to solve this problem is to set the correct environment variables in PHP so that, when `exec` is called, it is called within an environment that is already properly initialized to run rvm related things (like setting the ruby version).  But, most likely, there are certain safe_mode protections on PHP which prevent you from setting those environment variables in your PHP script.

The other solution, which is a bit of a hack, is to have your PHP script in the browser run the *same* ruby interpreter that you would run in the command line.  That is, instead of `exec('ruby some_ruby_file.rb')`, you would do `exec('/home/my_username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9/bin/ruby some_ruby_file.rb')` - I just made up that path to your ruby interpreter.  From the command line, run `which ruby` to find out the exact path to your ruby interpreter.  **BUT** you have to make sure that `www-data` has permission to run this ruby interpreter in your folder.  To avoid this hassle, though this is even more of a hack, is simply to make a copy of that ruby interpreter and place it in a bin folder owned by `www-data`, and have your PHP script `exec` that ruby interpreter.

Comment: Thank you, this answer helped me out a lot. I totally neglected the idea of this being a user issue. I ended up calling `ruby` by its full path (as you suggested). However, I wasn't able to include gems with this method. My application doesn't depend on any gems, so this solution works fine for me.

Comment: It all worked, but my script uses gems, can somebody help out ?

Comment: My scripts doesnt find gems**

Answer (score 0):

You must specify full path to ruby and gem_home.

Example, that got me working:

```
        var_dump(exec("
export GEM_HOME='/home/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0';
export GEM_PATH='/home/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0:/home/www/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global';
export MY_RUBY_HOME='/home/www/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0';

/home/www/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby public/okcredit.ge/scripts/restrictions-and-pledges-bot/crawler.rb"));
```